# useState + useContext como pasar valores de useState al Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs, usestate, context

Soy nuevo en reactjs. Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en la cual tengo 5 componentes.
En 4 de ellos obtengo un valor mediante useState de forma sencilla(solo devuelve string).
Entonces lo que deseo es poderle pasar esos valores a un 5to componente.
Para ello cree un Context.Provider en mi app principal.Mi problema es el cómo pasar los valores a ese Context.Provider
como ejemplo hice esto:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './components/appContext/AppContext'

import { MainApp } from './MainApp'

export const App = () => {


    const testValues = {
        myDomine: 'domine name',
        mySpace: 'space name',
        color: 'red',
        persons: '5 ',
        privacidad: true

    }


    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={testValues}>
            <MainApp/>

        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

y funciona tal y como lo deseo, el problema es como obtener los valores de testValues desde los otros componentes

por ejemplo seria:

```
const testValues = {
        myDomine: useStateValueComponent1,
        mySpace: useStateValueComponent2,
        color: useStateValueComponent3,
        persons: useStateValueComponent4,
        privacidad: useStateValueComponent5

    }
```

Gracias de antemano

**2da explicacion de mi problema**

lo que deseo es poder pasar los valores de estos 5 componentes al testValues, porque ya teniendo esos valores es facil disponer de ellos

```
function MainApp(){
  return(
    <div>
     <Child1/>  -->aqui obtengo el valor Domine
     <Child2 />  -->aqui obtengo el valor mySpace
      <Child3 />  -->aqui obtengo el valor color
     <Child4 />  -->aqui obtengo el valor persons
     <Child5 />  -->aqui obtengo el valor privacidad

     <Child6 />  -->este componente es el que debe recibir todos esos valores
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

para ello cree el antes mencionado Context.Provider

en la literatura que he leido menciona que esto debe hacerse mediante useReducer y hacer dispatch etc...pero, como los valores que obtengo en los componentes son tan sencillos estoy explorando esta via que pregunto aca.

Nuevamente gracias por el tiempo y la paciencia

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta en base a las modificaciones a la pregunta inicial, saludos

Answer (score 1):

#### Actualización

Una solución puede ser usando el hook `useContext`:

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext(null);
```

A continuación, se configura el objeto `testValues` como valor inicial de `useState`:

```
const [gState, setgState] = React.useState(testValues);
```

Luego, como ya se envolvió `MainApp` en el `Context Provider`, se puede usar el valor `value` en **cualquier profundidad dentro del árbol de componentes**, para esto se configura el provider para el hook `useContext->GlobalContext`:

```
<GlobalContext.Provider value={gState}>
     <MainApp/>
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

---

#### Crear una nueva copia del contexto desde Child Components

Después, se puede utilizar el setter `setgState` de `useState` para poder crear una nueva copia del valor del contexto `gState` desde cualquier child component y además, esta nueva copia estará disponible cada vez que se devuelva el componente `App`.

Para lograr esto, se envia un `objeto` en la propiedad `value` del contexto, este objeto contendrá las propiedades `gState` y una función handler `updatePrivacidad`, suponiendo que esta función va a manejar la propiedad `privacidad` de la estructura `testValues`, propuesta como estado inicial de contexto `gState`:

```
<GlobalContext.Provider value={{gState, updatePrivacidad}}>
       <MainApp/>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
```

En `App`, el código para `updatePrivacidad`:

```
function updatePrivacidad(value){
  console.log("nueva copia de gState desde ComponentePrivacidad"); 
  console.log("cambio privacidad de true a false");
  setgState({...gState, privacidad:value});
}
```

Finalmente, se consume la función handler en el componente `ComponentePrivacidad`, por medio del hook `useContext` y se codifica el procedimiento para obtener el nuevo valor de `privacidad`:

```
function ComponentePrivacidad(){
    //se llama al contexto y se destructura una funcion handler
      const {updatePrivacidad} = React.useContext(GlobalContext);
      //handler local
      function handlerGlobalState(){
        //obtienes el dato de alguna forma
        let privacidad = false;
        //se notifica del cambio en gState de Child a Parent
        //handle de context
        updatePrivacidad(privacidad)
      }

      return <button onClick={handlerGlobalState}>Update Privacidad</button>;

    }
```

Se puede repetir el patrón para las demás propiedades del objeto `testValues` (myDomine, mySpace, color etc...);

Por lo que veo, se tiene un componente para cada propiedad, mas el componente que necesita consumir todas estas propiedades en conjunto, que en este ejemplo sería `ChildTwo`.

Dejo una demostración, la profundidad del contexto es `MainApp->ChildTwo`

```js
const GlobalContext = React.createContext(null);
const testValues = {
        myDomine: '',
        mySpace: '',
        color: '',
        persons: '',
        privacidad: true
    }
   
function App(){
const [gState, setgState] = React.useState(testValues);

function updatePrivacidad(value){
  console.log("nueva copia de gState desde ComponentePrivacidad"); 
  console.log("cambio privacidad de true a false");
  setgState({...gState, privacidad:value});
}

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{gState, updatePrivacidad}}>
       <MainApp/>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}

function MainApp(){
  return(
    <div>
     <ComponentePrivacidad />
     <ChildTwo />
    </div>
  )
}

function ComponentePrivacidad(){
//se llama al contexto y se destructura una funcion handler
  const {updatePrivacidad} = React.useContext(GlobalContext);
  //handler local
  function handlerGlobalState(){
    //obtienes el dato de alguna forma
    let privacidad = false;
    //se notifica del cambio en gState de Child a Parent
    //handle de context
    updatePrivacidad(privacidad)
  }

  return <button onClick={handlerGlobalState}>Update Privacidad</button>;

}

function ChildTwo(){
  const valueFromContex = React.useContext(GlobalContext);
  console.log("valueFromContex",valueFromContex.gState);
  return null;
}



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

Esta es una propuesta, como lo mencionas hay diferentes formas de aproximarse a una solución, como por ejemplo usando el hook `useReducer`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sin embargo hice una edicion de la pregunta principal que me parece explica lo que deseo mejor que la primera vez basandome en tu ejemplo

Comment: al final lo use con useReducer porque no supe implementar tu respuesta, es una pena ser tan noob, si quieres te comparto mi repo para ilustrarme en esa via, si es de tu interes.saludos y gracias

Comment: Recuerda que puedes responder a tu propia pregunta, ver tu caso de uso con implementación `useReducer` va a ser un buen aporte a la comunidad, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por recordarme lo del aporte. espero que se le pueda sacar provecho de alguna forma

Answer (score 1):

En esta via explico la forma en la que puede pasar los valores de los componentes al Context

**Context**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AppContext = createContext(null)
```

**types**

```
export const types = {
    color: 'CHANGE_COLOR',

    inputComponent: 'CHANGE_INPUT_SPACE',

    inputSuffixComponent: 'CHANGE_INPUT_DOMINE',

    personas: 'CHANGE_PERSONAS',

    privacidad: 'CHANGE_PRIVACIDAD'


}
```

**Reducer**

```
import { types } from "../types/types";


export const appReducer = (state, action) => {



    const { payload, type } = action

    switch (type) {
        case types.color:
            return {
                ...state,
                color: payload,
            }
        case types.inputComponent:
            return {
                ...state,
                inputComponent: payload,
            }
        case types.inputSuffixComponent:
            return {
                ...state,
                inputSuffixComponent: payload,
            }
        case types.personas:
            return {
                ...state,
                personas: payload,
            }
        case types.privacidad:
            return {
                ...state,
                privacidad: payload,
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**App**

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

import { appReducer } from './reducer/appReducer'

import { Prueba } from './Prueba'
import { AppContext } from './context/AppContext'



export const App = () => {

    const initialState =
    {
        color: '#d8dfff',
        inputComponent: 'mi.espacio',
        inputSuffixComponent: 'mi.dominio',
        personas: 'Sólo yo',
        privacidad: 'Privado',

    }


    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);


    const handleChangeColor = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_COLOR', payload: value })
    }

    const handleChangeSpace = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_INPUT_SPACE', payload: value })
    }

    const handleChangeDomine = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_INPUT_DOMINE', payload: value })
    }

    const handleChangePersonas = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PERSONAS', payload: value })
    }

    const handleChangePrivacidad = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_PRIVACIDAD', payload: value })
    }





    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={
                {
                    ...state,
                    handleChangeColor,
                    handleChangeSpace,
                    handleChangeDomine,
                    handleChangePersonas,
                    handleChangePrivacidad,

                }
            }>
            <Prueba />
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

ahora vienen los componentes que necesito, para este caso de estudio voy a postear solo uno pues es lo mismo para los demas

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'
import { AppContext } from '../../context/AppContext'




export const ButtonTemas = () => {

    const { handleChangeColor } = useContext(AppContext)

    const colors = [
        '#39B0FF',
        '#04B58B',
        '#3E9C4B',
        '#B6BC00',
        '#E59100',
        '#E55C00',
        '#EE1F50',
        '#D6198A',
        '#B321F1',
        '#48B5FE'
    ]

    return (
        <div className='temas-btn' >
            {
                colors.map((color, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <Button shape="circle" style={{
                            backgroundColor: color,
                            color: color,
                            border: '1px solid',
                            width: '45px',
                            height: '47.54px',
                            flexGrow: '1',

                        }}
                            onClick={() => handleChangeColor(color)}
                        >{String(' ')}</Button>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div >
    )
}
```

y para obtener estos valores que ya estan en el context hago lo siguiente en el componente que necesito obtener dichos valores:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../../context/AppContext'

export const componenteDestino= () =>{

const { color,
        inputComponent,
        inputSuffixComponent,
        personas,
        privacidad,
    } = useContext(AppContext)



return(
.
.
.
)
```

y ya puedo utilizar dichos valores

Anteriormente cada componente individual obtenia los valores debido a un useState y no sabia(aun no se) si es factible y/o posible poder enviar esos datos al context, asi que utilice useReducer

en algun lugar ley algo como una especia de regla con la que se puede saber cuando utilizar useState y cuando utilizar useReducer, aqui lo comparto

Use useState if:

```
A) if you manage JavaScript primitives as state
B) if you have simple state transitions
C) if you want to have business logic within your component
D) if you have different properties that don’t change in any correlated manner and can be managed by multiple useState hooks
E) if your state is co-located to your component
F) if you’ve got a small application (but the lines are blurry here)
```

Use useReducer if:

```
A) if you manage JavaScript objects or arrays as state
B) if you have complex state transitions
C) if you want to move business logic into reducers
D) if you have different properties that are tied together and should be managed in one state object
E) if you want to update state deep down in your component tree
F) if you’ve got a medium size application (but the lines are blurry here)
G) if you want have an easier time testing it
H) if you want a more predictable and maintainable state architecture
```

y no puedo evitar decir aqui que lo anterior me tiene confundido actualmente jeje

Espero que este post les sea util en la medida de lo posible.

Gracias por todo