# ¿Cómo se relacionan los conceptos de contexto, provider y consumer en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo esa duda, en React no sé lo que se refiere por contexto, ni provider, ni consumer y por supuesto no sé como se relacionan entre sí. He mirado en la [documentación oficial de React](https://es.reactjs.org/) pero no me queda claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De lo general, se puede decir que `ReactJS Context` es una variable global `x` que va dentro de un componente `provider` que después, puede ser consumido  mediante el componente `consumer` desde cualquier otro componente en el árbol de componentes de la `App` y así, proveer el estado de la variable global `x`.

Además, esta variable global `x` se puede modificar usando el `consumer` en cualquier componente del árbol de componentes, esto ocasiona que se devuelva la `App` nuevamente con el estado actual de `x`.

> ReactJS Context: Sabe cuál es el contexto de la App, tiene información para los demás componentes, la cual  les puede proveer, basta con que la consuman.

[Demo Disponible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445089/usestate-usecontext-como-pasar-valores-de-usestate-al-context-provider/445105#445105)

Tiene muchos casos de uso, cuando usar context y cuando no, como usarlo etc...

Sugiero continuar en la [doc oficial](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)